# Date generated by swagger (springfox)

Tags: java, date, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a field defined in the swagger as:

```
appStartedDate:
   type: string
   format: date
```

I am expecting appStartedDate to be generated as a string **"2020-09-20"**. Instead, it's being generated as a LocalDate

```
"appStartedDate": {
      "year": 2020
      "month" : 09
      "day": 20
}
```

I am using **springfox-swagger2 v2.9.2**

What can we do keep the swagger specs as is (format: date) and still generate the date in "yyyy-mm-dd" forwat

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`
as shown below

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Date appStartedDate;
```

The above will solve your problem I believe.

You can also use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`